# Authentication and persisting token in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am using NextJS and it's Server-side Rendering

We use JWT for authentication

as a normal React app, we can use JWT on every request to the server and get the data

but we have some pages that will return different data based on user is logged in or not

and because NextJS fetches the data in the `getServerSideProps` function on the Server, we have not the JWT there, it's saved on the Client's `localStorage`

so How can I do the authentication on both Server-side and Client-side requests ?

I Only have JWT on the Client, should I put it in the `cookies` ?

What is the Best Practice

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late, but yes put it in a cookie, because cookie is available both on server and client side
You can use [nookies](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.npmjs.com/package/nookies&ved=2ahUKEwitl5rf1uj0AhW4iv0HHUb0AdsQFnoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw33kyUZq5PimN6LRjnzF03K)  for workimg with SSR and CSR cookies